# Exception : The given filter must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces when implementing custom filter in WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build my custom filter for authentication, but I am running on this problem when I try to run my WebAPI solution:

> The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following
>   filter interfaces: System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.

The error occurs in FilterConfig class:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
   {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthAttribute());
   }
}
```

In the line where I am trying to add AuthAttribute to filters.

This is whole AuthAttribute class:

```
using Examino.Business;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.IdentityModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace Examino.API.Filters
{
    public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public ITokenProviderService TokenProviderService { get; set; }

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            SetDependencies(actionContext);

            if (!IsAuthorized(actionContext) && !SkipAuthorization(actionContext))
            {
                if (Authenticate(actionContext) == AuthenticationErrors.UNAUTHORIZED)
                {
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
                }
                else if (Authenticate(actionContext) == AuthenticationErrors.TOKEN_EXPIRED)
                {
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                        //token expired status code?
                        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetDependencies(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var requestScope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();

            if (TokenProviderService == null)
            {
                TokenProviderService = requestScope.GetService(typeof(ITokenProviderService)) as ITokenProviderService;
            }
        }

        private AuthenticationErrors Authenticate(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> authHeaderValues;
            actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authHeaderValues);

            try
            {
                if (authHeaderValues != null)
                {
                    string bearerToken = authHeaderValues.ElementAt(0);
                    string token = bearerToken.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.Substring(7) : bearerToken;

                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = TokenProviderService.ValidateJwtToken(token);
                    if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null)
                    {
                        return AuthenticationErrors.AUTHORIZED;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException)
            {
                return AuthenticationErrors.TOKEN_EXPIRED;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return AuthenticationErrors.UNAUTHORIZED;
            }

            return AuthenticationErrors.UNAUTHORIZED;
        }

        private bool SkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            Contract.Assert(actionContext != null);

            return actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()
                || actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
        }

        private enum AuthenticationErrors
        {
            UNAUTHORIZED,
            TOKEN_EXPIRED,
            AUTHORIZED
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute` class.

Here is a stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The given filter instance must implement
>   one or more of the following filter interfaces:
>   System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection.ValidateFilterInstance(Object
>   instance) +403
>   System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection.AddInternal(Object filter,
>   Nullable`1 order) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection.Add(Object filter) +31
>   Examino.API.FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection
>   filters) in C:\examino\src\Examino.API\App_Start\FilterConfig.cs:12
>   Examino.API.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in
>   C:\examino\src\Examino.API\Global.asax.cs:22
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The given filter instance must implement
>   one or more of the following filter interfaces:
>   System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +540
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The given filter instance must implement
>   one or more of the following filter interfaces:
>   System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +125    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +731

Even if I implement for example `IAuthenticationFilter` interface same exception is thrown anyhow.

Did someone had a similar exception? I was unable to find something more about this in WebAPI.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Solved: The problem was place of registration of Filter. In MVC you would register filters in `FilterConfing` class, but in WebAPI you are doing this in Register method of `WebApiConfig` class like this:

```
config.Filters.Add(new AuthAttribute());
```

Everything works now.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is realy strange, but VS generates Global.asax for web api with separate FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters).